# Unable to write to external hard drive

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive

I am unable to write to my external hard drive.

This is the output of the 'mount' command:

```
joris@joris $ mount
[...]
/dev/sda1 on /media/joris/LACIE4TB1 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
[...]
```

and the output of gparted:

```
joris@joris $ sudo gparted -l
[...]
Model: LaCie P9230 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      258kB  4001GB  4001GB  primary               lba
[...]
```

I have tried running:

```
joris@joris $ sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sdb1
```

And although that makes the folders (in the explorer) appear read/write capable, I am still unable to copy, or write anything to this drive.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What happens when you try to write something?

Comment: If I try it in a file explorer, nothing happens. If I try to set the permissions in a command prompt, it refuses
    joris@joris $ sudo chmod -R a+x .
will simply go over all files, telling me that it can not set the permissions.
The strange thing is that this hard drive is not broken or anything. I have been able to put files on it (couple of months ago).

Comment: You cannot change ownership nor permissions on Windows file types like FAT32 or NTFS. Only the mount controls settings. Where did the 0077 come from? Mount with fmask=0113,dmask=0002 and see if it works. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: Could you be more specific, and give the command?
I'm quite out of my comfort-zone with this problem.

Comment: I executed:
sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0113,dmask=0002 /dev/sdb1
and then tried to cp a file to a folder in the hard drive. It promptly spewed out this error message:
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/media/joris/LACIE4TB/movies/t/’: No such file or directory

Comment: In your `fstab` the disk is `/dev/sda1`, but in your `sudo mount` command you use `/dev/sdb1`. Which disk are you trying to mount?  Also, when it is mounted, what is the output of `ls -la /media/joris/LACIE4TB1`?

Comment: Also, in your mount output, the mount point is `/media/joris/LACIE4TB1` whereas your error message refers to directory `/media/joris/LACIE4TB`. The names do not match.

Comment: I tried the mount command again, sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0002,fmask=0113 /dev/sda1. But the directory remains read-only.